# Numpy array of strings: how to group elemenents in one array based on elements in another array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array(['123_H2O_56', '345_CO2', 'H6C6_test', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O'])
b = np.array(['H2O', 'CO2', 'H6C6'])
```

I need to group elements in "a" numpy array based on the values in "b" numpy array and save the result to the third numpy array.
I know how to do it with for loop, but I guess there might be better solution.
Output should look like this:

```
c = [['123_H2O_56', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O'],
     ['345_CO2'],
     ['H6C6_test']]
```

Comment: Since numpy is not ideal to work with text nor to produce ragged outputs, a loop is most likely the best approach.

Comment: First of all, Numpy as no group-by functions. There are several post on this. Moreover, Numpy does not support natively-jagged arrays (array containing variables arrays) and it is not made for that anyway. Additionally, Numpy is often not great for string since it is designed for NUMerical computation in PYthon (hense the name "Num"+"py"). Pandas is better suited for all of that (see the doc and the numerous past posts about that).

Comment: @mozway a loop is certainly _not_ the best approach. Pandas has string vectorisation, as Jerome indicated.

Comment: @Reinderien AFAIK not if you want to extract arbitrary text. If you want to extract a given position/slice (e.g. the 6th to 8th characters), sure you can vectorize, but not here.

Comment: Depends on a lot of things. @user16613865 - are all of the string fragments of interest guaranteed to be separated by underscores as in your sample data?

Comment: Strings always will be separated by underscore. I didn't realize that numpy is not efficient with strings... Solution of @mozway with pandas and regex worked best for me. Thank you very much everyone for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and a regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

a = np.array(['123_H2O_56', '345_CO2', 'H6C6_test', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O'])
b = np.array(['H2O', 'CO2', 'H6C6'])

pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, b))
# '(H2O|CO2|H6C6)'

s = pd.Series(a)
out = s.groupby(s.str.extract(pattern, expand=False), sort=False).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
H2O     [123_H2O_56, check_H2O, 67_H2O]
CO2                           [345_CO2]
H6C6                        [H6C6_test]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come to mind, and will have different performance characteristics. The first is a fully-vectorised (no loops, no `map`, no `apply`) method that relies on a cross-merge, so has memory risk for large datasets. The second is semivectorised and runs an outer loop on matching compounds with an inner step that's a vectorised `.str.contains`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array(['123_H2O_56', '345_CO2', 'H6C6_test', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O'])
b = np.array(['H2O', 'CO2', 'H6C6'])


def full_vectorise():
    fragments = pd.Series(
        name='stub', data=a, index=pd.Index(name='stub', data=a),
    ).str.split(pat='_', regex=False, expand=True)

    combos = pd.merge(
        left=pd.Series(name='compound', data=b),
        right=fragments.reset_index(), how='cross',
    )
    combos = combos[
        (
            combos.iloc[:, 2:].eq(combos['compound'], axis=0)
        ).any(axis=1)
    ]
    return combos[['compound', 'stub']]


def semivectorise():
    stubs = pd.Series(name='stub', data=a)
    combos = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({
            'compound': compound,
            'stub': stubs[stubs.str.contains(compound)],
        })
        for compound in b
    ])
    return combos


print(semivectorise())
```

```
  compound        stub
0      H2O  123_H2O_56
3      H2O   check_H2O
4      H2O      67_H2O
1      CO2     345_CO2
2     H6C6   H6C6_test
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like useful "vectorization" to me. For instance, with only 1000 items in `a` and `b` either of those approaches is a few hundred times slower than my simple regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Could you solve this with pure numpy? Yes of course. But its alittle messy:

import numpy as np

```
v = b[np.vectorize(np.char.find)(a[:,None], b).argmax(1)]
w = v.argsort()
np.split(a[w], np.arange(1, v.size)[v[w][:-1] != v[w][1:]])

[array(['345_CO2'], dtype='<U10'), array(['123_H2O_56', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O'], dtype='<U10'), array(['H6C6_test'], dtype='<U10')]
```

You could loop through the result of `np.split` to end with a list of lists instead of a list of arrays

```
[list(i) for i in np.split(a[w], np.unique(v[w],return_index = True)[1][1:])]

[['345_CO2'], ['123_H2O_56', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O'], ['H6C6_test']]
```

---

Note that the code `np.arange(1, v.size)[v[w][:-1] != v[w][1:]]` is similar to `np.unique(v[w], return_index = True)[1][1:]`

Answer (score 1):

For grouping tasks I like to use `collections.defaultdict`.

Starting with lists (arrays are slower when iterating):

```
In [7]: a = ['123_H2O_56', '345_CO2', 'H6C6_test', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O']
   ...: b = ['H2O', 'CO2', 'H6C6']
```

Create a defaultdict that will initialize a value with an empty list.

```
In [8]: from collections import defaultdict
In [9]: dd = defaultdict(list)
```

Then just add strings from `a` to a substring's list:

```
In [10]: for astr in a:
    ...:     alist = astr.split('_')
    ...:     for x in alist:
    ...:         if x in b:
    ...:             dd[x].append(astr)
    ...:             

In [11]: dd
Out[11]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'H2O': ['123_H2O_56', 'check_H2O', '67_H2O'],
             'CO2': ['345_CO2'],
             'H6C6': ['H6C6_test']})
```

An alternate interation

```
In [16]: for astr in a:
    ...:     for key in b:
    ...:         if key in astr:
    ...:             dd[key].append(astr)
```

My guess is that a pure python match like this will be fastest for smallist lists.  That's true for many list alternatives to "vectorized' `numpy` code.  `pandas` tends to have even higher setup times.  I don't have a feel for the speeds of things like `group_by`, `merge` etc.  `pandas` uses python strings instead of the `numpy` fixed length ones, but I don't know if its `str` methods improve on the base python ones.  `numpy` has some `np.char` functions that apply string methods to elements of arrays, but they aren't any faster than list comprehensions.